# How to package an executable and the library it depends on, in Autotools

Tags: c, makefile, autotools

I'm new to autotools and I've been searching for an example of how to package up a library and an executable using autotools. The executable depends on the library so the library will have to be built first.

So far I've got the library packaged up on it's own, and then I've been able to compile the executable and link to the library once that is installed. Here is my Makefile.am for that process:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.1.0.0.la
libfoo_1_0_0_la_SOURCES = libfoo.c
library_includedir=$(includedir)
library_include_HEADERS = libfoo.h
```

Then in the configure.ac file I added the line `LT_INIT` in the appropriate place. Everything builds nicely and works. I have a file foo.c that uses the library that I can compile with `gcc foo.c -o foo -lfoo`, however I'd like to extend the autotools package to include the foo executable, I can't work out how to do this. I've modified the Makefile.am to look like this:

```
bin_PROGRAMS=foo
foo_SOURCES=foo.c
foo_DEPENDENCIES=libfoo.1.0.0.la
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.1.0.0.la
libfoo_1_0_0_la_SOURCES = libfoo.c
library_includedir=$(includedir)
library_include_HEADERS = libfoo.h
```

My `configure.ac` file is unchanged. Everything runs fine until I get to make, at this point it seems that foo.c is compiled first and obviously throws lots of errors as the functions in libfoo aren't available. I've searched for an example like this but so far not had any luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the proper way to do it.

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmoovcaps.la
libmovcaps_la_SOURCES = libmoovcaps.c
include_HEADERS = libmoovcaps.h
bin_PROGRAMS = moovcaps
moovcaps_SOURCES = moovcaps.c
moovcaps_LDADD = libmoovcaps.la
```

P.S.: Why do you have numbers in your libmoovcaps.la? You can pass the `-version-info` flag via `libmoovcaps_LDFLAGS`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the -version-info flag, this was my first attempt with autotools.

Comment: This helped me much. I was trying with something like moovcaps_LDADD = -lmoovcaps. Although a local build was successful, plugging this to bitbake was failing. This solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I put this in my `Makefile.am`:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.1.0.0.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = libfoo.c
library_includedir=$(includedir)
library_include_HEADERS = libfoo.h
bin_PROGRAMS=foo
foo_SOURCES=foo.c
foo_DEPENDENCIES=libfoo.1.0.0.la
foo_LDADD= libfoo.o
```

This seems to work now :)